# Making HTTP request and authenticating with AD using CredentialCache

Tags: c#, authentication, httprequest, httpwebrequest

I am making a http request and need to authenticate using AD credentials. I am able to successfully do so my doing:

```
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypasssword");
```

However, I was trying this by using

```
 webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password);
```

However that returns a 401. Is CredentialCache not the correct way to do this? And is this a way to pull the current users username and password to pass this way or would I need to prompt the user for this input?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the value in `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`?

Comment: I have, seems to return empty strings for username, domain, and password. However it does return secure password {System.Security.SecureString}

Comment: If you want to authenticate with the current user, simply set `WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials` property. NTLM and Kerberos are using hashes, no actual credentials are passed as with basic authentication. However, most servers do fall back to basic. This is why your first method works. Still, there is no documented way to get the current user's password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate with the current user, simply set `WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials` property as there is no documented way to get the current user's password.

Anyway, what you want is either NTLM or Kerberos authentication, that will on their end reach out to local Windows user store or the domain services to validate the authentication. They are using two and respectively three-party handshake with complex messages and hashes, but no actual credentials are passed like in the case of the `basic` authentication. However, most servers do fall back to basic. This is why your first method works.